# Extending UIScrollView when it fills up with more content

Tags: objective-c

Ok, so i got a scrollview to load when an user logs in to my application. When the user is authenticated, i need to create a scrollview programmatically. To do so, i have the following code:

```
[scrollView removeFromSuperview];

        UIScrollView *view = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, applicationFrame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];


        //-- get the y-coordinate of the view
        CGFloat viewCenterY = self.view.center.y;
        //--calculate how much visible space is left
        CGFloat freeSpaceHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - keyboardBounds.size.height;
        //-- calculate how much the scrollview must scroll
        CGFloat scrollAmount = viewCenterY - freeSpaceHeight / 2.0;

        if(scrollAmount < 0) scrollAmount = 0;

        //set the new scrollsize contentview
        view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(applicationFrame.size.width,         applicationFrame.size.height + keyboardBounds.size.height);

        //scroll the scrollview
        [view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, scrollAmount) animated:YES];

            for(int v = 0; v < 15; v++){
                CGFloat yCoord = v * 100;
                UILabel *mijnLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, yCoord, 200, 50)];

                mijnLabel.text = @"1337";
                mijnLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:20];
                mijnLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

                [view addSubview:mijnLabel];
                [mijnLabel release];
            }


            [self.view addSubview:view];

            [view release];


        }
```

How do i extend my view according to the amount of labels i added? I also want to know how i can make my scrollview fill up the entire screen.. My scrollview is now only filling up the screen when in portrait mode.

This is the login screen that gets removed:

```
 [scrollView removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to keep track of numbers of label that you are adding into the scroll view. suppose if your label's height is 50 then take a variable and make a total of all label's height and give a new frame to your scroll view. like :

```
        view.frame = CGRectmake(0,0,applicationFrame.size.width,totalHeightOfLabel);
        [self.view addSubview:view];

        [view release];
```

hope this will give a idea...